# Inductive/Deductive Arguments, Appeals to ignorance, Begging the Question

Tags: critical-thinking

Is every sound argument a inductive argument?

Can arguments be both inductive and deductive?

Are arguments that do not prove their premise, appeals to ignorance?

Are arguments that use their conclusion as premise begging the question?

Are arguments that use conjoin premises valid?

Comment: Is this your Philosophy 101 homework?

Answer (score 1):

Sound arguments can only be DEDUCTIVE.  Inductive arguments can be Cogent. Arguments do not have to be either deductive or inductive.  For example there are abductive arguments.  I will leave that to you to search online. As for the fallacies you mention those have exact definitions that you need to know.  So the answer to those questions about appeals to ignorance and begging the question above in you question is NO.  Your terminology is way off by the way.  Arguments do not have to prove their premises.  The premises ought to be objectively true and then when the relationship of the premises is correct true premises must yield a true conclusion.